# How to download Open Street Map data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, data, download

I'm trying download data from OSM in QGIS via Openlayers plugin. Downloading is successfull, but when I add layer to project, many of the features are missing. 
Is there any limitation, or does anybody know why the data is not complete?

Comment: Awesome buddy! Although my comment doesn't exactly answer your question, I will post it as an answer for the convenience of others as an alternative method to extract OSM data.

Comment: The openlayers plugin? That adds base maps. It doesn't download vector data ...

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to use the QuickOSM plugin. It allows to download all data for a small area, or filter for specific data for larger regions.

If you just want a nice background, take the QuickMapServices plugin. It offers the same layers as the Openlayers plugin, but can handle projection conversions better.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative source to download OSM data is from the **OSMDownloader** plugin which you may need to download/install from the toolbar:

*Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins*

This allows you to draw a rectangle over the canvas in which to extract the OSM data.