# OpenLayers Plugin QGIS Essen 2.14.3 defect?

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I'm using QGIS Essen 2.14.3 for analysing gpx-routes.

After installing the latest Version, it is not possible to install "OpenLayers-Plugin". Python says: "module" object has no attribute "wkbCurve".

Can this error be avoided?

I need OMS, because I want to show only buildings, ways in the background of the gpx-routes.

Comment: Hi Reike, either try the **QuickMapServices** plugin or check AndreJ's answer in this post: [How to download Open Street Map data in QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180788/how-to-download-open-street-map-data-in-qgis)

Comment: ... or follow the advices at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200794/openlayer-plugin-error-after-installing-update to get an earlier version of the plugin.